# Взаимная блокировка

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-8, deadlock

```
public class test implements Runnable {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    test() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Главный поток");
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "Соперничающий поток");
        t.start();
        a.foo(b); // получить блокировку для объекта a в этом потоке исполнения
        System.out.println("Назад в главный поток");
    }
    public void run() {
        b.bar(a); // получить блокировку для объекта b в другом потоке исполнения
        System.out.println("Назад в другой поток");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }
}
class A {
    synchronized void foo(B b) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " вошел в метод A.foo()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("class A is break");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " пытается вызвать метод B.last()");
        b.last();
    }
    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("В методе A.last()");
    }
}
    class B {
    synchronized void bar(A a) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " вошел в метод B.bar()");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("class B is break");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " пытается вызвать метод A.last()");
        a.last();
    }
    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("В методе A.last()");
    }
}
```

Главный поток входит в монитор объекта A. Соперничающий входит в монитор объекта B. Почему когда поток исполнения в объекте A пытается вызвать синхронизированный метод для объекта B он блокируется? Почему когда поток исполнения в объекте B пытается вызвать синхронизированный метод для объекта A, то он будет ждать вечно? Я так понял монитор распространяется на весь объект что-ли, а не на метод в объекте?

Answer (score 0):

Да, монитор распространяется на весь объект.
Запись

```
class A {
    synchronized void aVoid() {
    }
}
```

аналогична записи

```
class A {
     void aVoid() {
         synchronized(this) {
         }
     }
}
```

То есть, при выполнении синхронизированного метода или блока, синхронизированного с текущим объектом, весь объект блокируется, и у него нельзя вызвать никакие другие синхронизированные методы.
Такая взаимная блокировка, как в вашем примере, называется Deadlock.